# Biztalk mapper to work with Master Data Service Web Service

Tags: web-services, biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-mapper, master-data-services

Im having a problem updating Master Data located in Microsoft Master Data Service. Im using Biztalk 2010 and im reading from flat file.

The problem is that I cannot find out how to map everything in the mapper and keep getting the same error: *Inner exception: Received unexpected message type 'http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope#Fault' does not match expected type 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/masterdataservices/2009/09#EntityMembersUpdateResponse'.*

Does anyone have any kind of tutorial on how to fix this? I know this could be done using code, but I want to try it out with mapper.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you web service call return a fault response message instead of the message you and your mapping expects.

If your actually expecting a custom fault message and want to handle that there is a write up on how to do that [here](http://martinbring.blogspot.se/2009/02/handling-fault-message.html).